# How to dynamic pivot mysql table?

Tags: mysql

Hi I've got the following mysql table:

[image]

I need to pivot these datas to look like the following:

[image]

The scadenza is not always the same and can change therefore I believe I need to create the pivot table dynamically, This is the stored procedure I've tried:

```
BEGIN
SELECT

    GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT("MAX(IF(scadenza='", scadenza, "',importo ,'')) AS '", scadenza, "'"), "
"
      )INTO @answers
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT scadenza,  
                      importo
                 FROM ripartizione_rate
                 
    ) A;

    SET @query :=
      CONCAT(
        'SELECT DISTINCT condomino, anagrafica,', @answers,
          'FROM ripartizione_rate
       GROUP BY condomino, anagrafica'
      );
      
PREPARE statement FROM @query;
    EXECUTE statement;
END
```

The result I get is very close but I get the date repeated as you can see in the image below:

[image]

Can please anyboby halp me to fix this problem? Many thanks for your help

This is the dump text for the table

```
INSERT INTO `ripartizione_rate` (`id`, `preventivo`, `piano_rateale`, `condomino`, `anagrafica`, `immobile`, `descrizione`, `scadenza`, `stato_pagamento`, `importo`, `importo_pagato`, `importo_residuo`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 19, 11, 3, 'Rata Num.1', '2021-01-01', 0, '208.38', '0.00', '0.00'),
(2, 1, 1, 12, 15, 3, 'Rata Num.1', '2021-01-01', 0, '208.38', '0.00', '0.00'),
(3, 1, 1, 10, 15, 5, 'Rata Num.1', '2021-01-01', 0, '500.10', '0.00', '0.00'),
(4, 1, 1, 20, 17, 3, 'Rata Num.1', '2021-01-01', 0, '83.35', '0.00', '0.00'),
(5, 1, 1, 19, 11, 3, 'Rata Num.2', '2021-05-01', 0, '208.31', '0.00', '0.00'),
(6, 1, 1, 12, 15, 3, 'Rata Num.2', '2021-05-01', 0, '208.31', '0.00', '0.00'),
(7, 1, 1, 10, 15, 5, 'Rata Num.2', '2021-05-01', 0, '499.95', '0.00', '0.00'),
(8, 1, 1, 20, 17, 3, 'Rata Num.2', '2021-05-01', 0, '83.33', '0.00', '0.00'),
(9, 1, 1, 19, 11, 3, 'Rata Num.3', '2021-09-01', 0, '208.31', '0.00', '0.00'),
(10, 1, 1, 12, 15, 3, 'Rata Num.3', '2021-09-01', 0, '208.31', '0.00', '0.00'),
(11, 1, 1, 10, 15, 5, 'Rata Num.3', '2021-09-01', 0, '499.95', '0.00', '0.00'),
(12, 1, 1, 20, 17, 3, 'Rata Num.3', '2021-09-01', 0, '83.33', '0.00', '0.00');
```

Comment: Please post table and data sample in textual formats, not as images. I want to help but I don't have the time to re-write everything from your image posts if I want to recreate and do some testing. If you post them in textual format, it'll be much easier to **copy & paste**. Don't need real data, fake data will do and don't need to format it beautifully.

Comment: Hi @FaNo_FN thanks for your reply I've attached mysql dump on the question, I hope this is what you were asking? many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subquery part here:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT("MAX(IF(scadenza='", scadenza, "',importo ,'')) AS '", scadenza, "'"), "
"
      )INTO @answers
    FROM (
      SELECT DISTINCT scadenza,          <----
                      importo            <---- this subquery
                 FROM ripartizione_rate  <---- 
    ) A
```

returns the following result:

```
+------------+---------+
| scadenza   | importo |
+------------+---------+
| 2021-01-01 |  208.38 |
| 2021-01-01 |  500.10 |
| 2021-01-01 |   83.35 |
| 2021-05-01 |  208.31 |
| 2021-05-01 |  499.95 |
| 2021-05-01 |   83.33 |
| 2021-09-01 |  208.31 |
| 2021-09-01 |  499.95 |
| 2021-09-01 |   83.33 |
+------------+---------+
```

Each date returns 3 rows due to the `DISTINCT` combination of `scadenza, importo`. If you run `SELECT @answers;` after the variable being assigned then you'll get:

```
SELECT @answers;
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|  @answers                                                   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| MAX(IF(scadenza='2021-01-01',importo ,'')) AS '2021-01-01'  |
| ,MAX(IF(scadenza='2021-01-01',importo ,'')) AS '2021-01-01' |
| ,MAX(IF(scadenza='2021-01-01',importo ,'')) AS '2021-01-01' |
| ,MAX(IF(scadenza='2021-05-01',importo ,'')) AS '2021-05-01' |
| ,MAX(IF(scadenza='2021-05-01',importo ,'')) AS '2021-05-01' |
| ,MAX(IF(scadenza='2021-05-01',importo ,'')) AS '2021-05-01' |
| ,MAX(IF(scadenza='2021-09-01',importo ,'')) AS '2021-09-01' |
| ,MAX(IF(scadenza='2021-09-01',importo ,'')) AS '2021-09-01' |
| ,MAX(IF(scadenza='2021-09-01',importo ,'')) AS '2021-09-01' |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Whereas what you really want is just 3 distinctive dates instead of 3x3 distinctive dates. Therefore, the fix is quite simple really, you just need to remove the column `importo` from the subquery:

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT("MAX(IF(scadenza='", scadenza, "',importo ,'')) AS '", scadenza, "'"), "") INTO @answers
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT scadenza
            FROM ripartizione_rate
    ) A;
    
 SELECT @answers;
 SET @query :=
      CONCAT(
        'SELECT DISTINCT condomino, anagrafica,', @answers2,
          'FROM ripartizione_rate
       GROUP BY condomino, anagrafica
       ORDER BY condomino, anagrafica'
      );

SELECT @query;

PREPARE statement FROM @query;
EXECUTE statement;
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=93715f1a0f73e0126952d2dad3d496e4)

Comment: Hi @FaNo_FN that is amazing many thanks. Can I also ask something else? If I add WHERE preventivo = preventivoID into@answers then If there is no specified preventivo ID in the database I get the following error Error Code: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1 how can I sort it out? Thanks again for your time

Comment: I'm not sure if it's version specific but when I try it in the fiddle, it doesn't give any error if the looked up id is not in database. Here's the test https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8424b5ba7d7a87f5e350884a1f946e95

Comment: Hi I'm using mysql 5.7.32 on local machine with MAMP not idea why this is happening. On phpMyAdmin I get The following query has failed: "SET @p0='2'; CALL `test`(@p0); "

Comment: The `@p0` variable is set with the value you want to lookup, correct? and I assume `test` in `CALL test` is a procedure? What is the purpose? If you're having problem with `test` procedure, I think that is sufficient reason to post a different question but if it's a simple issue, we'll try to figure out here. Can you update the fiddle and insert the relevant codes? Insert the code(s) then click the button `Run` on top of the fiddle. It will generate new link and you can paste the new link here. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=4fd205dfa89fda2dc38d345f516f5842

Comment: Hi, the problem is that it works in the fiddle, if i pass 2 as value for preventivo then I get null wich is what I want. But in phpMyAdmn I get this error "MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL' at line 1 " I could execute another query before calling the procedure to check first if the preventivo ID exist in the database but I'm trying to avoid another query if possible.

Comment: You probably can make use of other functions like `IFNULL(@p0, replacement_value)`, or maybe  a `CASE` expression? That will -probably- at least won't require another query.